# How delegation work if UITableViewController added to other UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I want to present a UITableViewController in a UIView, I have a workaround, but I want to understand why it works this way.

This is how the scenario looks like:
- Created a new Single View Application
- In IB added a view to the main view
- Created an outlet for the view:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *placeholderView;
```

- Added a new UITableViewController with XIB to the project
- Changed numberOfSectionsInTableView to return 1, numberOfRowsInSection to return 10, and cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"hello";
```

- In ViewController file ViewDidLoad method:

```
ORGTableViewController *tableView = [[ORGTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ORGTableViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.placeholderView addSubview:tableView.tableView];
```

Now the table appears in placeholderView but, it's empty. In TableViewController file InitWithStyle, and ViewDidLoad methods are called. But none of numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, and cellForRowAtIndexPath are called.

Also tried to add this code in AppDelegate to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, and it's —*working* as expected, cells with text are appear:

```
ORGTableViewController *tableViewController = [[ORGTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ORGTableViewController" bundle:nil];

self.window.rootViewController = tableViewController;
```

So it works, and it looks like delegation messed up somehow as I added UITableViewController to UIView, workaround is easy... ViewController, viewDidLoad method:

```
ORGTableViewController *tableViewController = [[ORGTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ORGTableViewController" bundle:nil];
tableViewController.tableView.delegate = tableViewController;

[self.placeholderView addSubview:tableViewController.tableView];
```

Do you know why delegation work this way?

THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question itself has the answer. In the first code, you were not setting the deletage where as in your second code, you are setting the delegate as `tableViewController.tableView.delegate = tableViewController;` which will call the delegate methods implemented in `tableViewController`.

If you are planning to implement delegate methods in your `placeholderView` class, you need to set the delegate as `` `tableViewController.tableView.delegate = self; `` and then implement all the delegates in `placeholderView` class. That would have worked.

If you just need a `UITableView`, you can also consider subclassing the `UITableView` class and add it as the subview of `placeholderView`.